# unexpected end of line using endif

Tags: linux

I am trying to source the script below, and I get this error:

> bash: csh.cshrc: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I have not been able to find an answer, any help would be great, thanks.

---

#### `/etc/csh.cshrc: system-wide .cshrc file for csh(1) and tcsh(1)`

```
if ($?tcsh && $?prompt) then

    bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line # Home
    bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line # Home rxvt
    bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode    # Ins
    bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char       # Delete
    bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line       # End
    bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line       # End rxvt

    set autoexpand
    set autolist
    set prompt = "%U%m%u:%B%~%b%# "
endif
```

Comment: If it were a bash script, it would require a semicolon before the `then`

Comment: You are trying to use `bash` to execute a `csh` script.  But `csh` scripts require a `csh`-compatible shell such as `tcsh` -- `bash` is not.

Comment: 13 lines in your code snippet. line 16 in the error.